# How to integrate content type to webform Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, nodes, webforms

I have a content type called "student".

now I want to set that content type as select option component in webform.

Are there any way to do so? thanks,

Comment: in my opinion your question is vague, I suggest that you can add more information to your question about, for example, what do you want to display in the list, the list of content of that content type to select one or several nodes? and after that, what do you want that happens?

Comment: Do you want that content to show up in the Webform content type when an admin is creating a new webform? Or on the actual webform for a user?

Answer (score 2):

Tvphong, I think that the best way to go about doing this is by using a custom module so that you can then integrate that content type within the select list of preloaded options.

Perhaps [this link](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2012/04/11/drupal-7-dynamic-select-options-for-webform/) can serve you well in this.

What I ended up doing is a slight tweak of this. So my custom module looks something like this (which is for location content types):

```
<?php 

/**
 * Reference:  http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2012/04/11/drupal-7-dynamic-select-options-for-webform/
 * The following piece of code is based on the blog post above
 */
function webform_options_webform_select_options_info() {
 $items = array();

 if (function_exists('get_location_titles')) {
  $items['location_titles'] = array(
    'title' => t('Location titles'),
    'options callback' => '_get_location_titles',
    );
 }

 return $items;
}

function _get_location_titles() {
 $options = array();
 $type = "location";

 $result = db_query('SELECT nid, title FROM {node} n WHERE n.type = :tname', array(':tname' => $type));
 foreach ($result as $row) {
  $options[$row->nid] = $row->title;
 }
 return $options;
}
```